# NServiceBus does not publish on test system

Tags: c#, .net, messaging, nservicebus

I have the following Setup:

- One service called `CoreHost` should receive a `ExecuteWorkflowByAttributeCommand` which is `Bus.Send` to it and publish `WorkflowByAttributeExecuted` afterwards.
- One "client" which uses `Bus.Send` to execute the command and is subscribed to the `WorkflowByAttributeExecuted` message.

The Handler looks like this:

```
    public void Handle(WorkflowByAttributeCommand message)
    {
        MessageLifetimeLogger.Info("Received WorkflowByAttribute Command", ...);

        var log = _executor.ExecuteWithLog(message.Attribute, 
                                           message.SerializedWorkItem,
                                           message.Id);
        Bus.Publish(new WorkflowByAttributeExecuted(message.Id, log));

        MessageLifetimeLogger.Info("Completed WorkflowByAttribute Command", ...);
    }
```

On my development machine it runs fine but on our test system the same does not.

**The command is received and the handler is obviously executed (the log contains the appropriate entries) but no message is published.**

What surprises me is that the log looks completely different on both machines.

The working machines log contains

```
Received message MHP.Domain.Common.Core.Messaging.WorkflowByAttribute.WorkflowByAttributeCommand, MHP.Domain.Common.Core, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null with ID 6e15d4f7-7aa7-4be3-bd80-e70497bc5051\66585 from sender TestServerQueue@PC-SB-11
Activating: WorkflowByAttributeHandler 
// some log entries generated by the Handle method
Sending message MHP.Domain.Common.Core.Messaging.WorkflowByAttribute.WorkflowByAttributeExecuted, MHP.Domain.Common.Core, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null with ID 6e15d4f7-7aa7-4be3-bd80-e70497bc5051\66587 to destination TestServerQueue@PC-SB-11.
WorkflowByAttributeHandler Done.
```

whereby the not working machines log contains only

```
Received message MHP.Domain.Common.Core.Messaging.WorkflowByAttribute.WorkflowByAttributeCommand, MHP.Domain.Common.Core, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null with ID 6e15d4f7-7aa7-4be3-bd80-e70497bc5051\66585 from sender TestServerQueue@PC-SB-11
// some log entries generated by the Handle method
```

However all message types seem to be registered successfully:

```
Subscribing TestServerQueue@VM-SCRUM-VLOG to message type MHP.Domain.Common.Core.Messaging.WorkflowByAttribute.WorkflowByAttributeExecuted, MHP.Domain.Common.Core, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null |  
Subscribing TestServerQueue@VM-SCRUM-VLOG to message type MHP.Domain.Common.Core.Messaging.WorkflowByAttribute.WorkflowByAttributeCommand, MHP.Domain.Common.Core, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null |
```

The app.config of the server looks like

```
<MsmqTransportConfig
    InputQueue="CoreHostQueue"
    ErrorQueue="ErrorQueue"
    NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"
    MaxRetries="5" />

<UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

The other one contains the message mappings

```
<MsmqTransportConfig
  InputQueue="TestServerQueue"
  ErrorQueue="ErrorQueue"
  NumberOfWorkerThreads="2"
  MaxRetries="5" />

<UnicastBusConfig>
  <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <add Messages="MHP.Domain.Common.Core.Messaging.WorkflowByAttribute.WorkflowByAttributeCommand, MHP.Domain.Common.Core" Endpoint="CoreHostQueue"/>
    <add Messages="MHP.Domain.Common.Core.Messaging.WorkflowByAttribute.WorkflowByAttributeExecuted, MHP.Domain.Common.Core" Endpoint="CoreHostQueue"/>
  </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscriptions where not stored durably. Thanks to Andreas Öhlund for help!

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the publisher will only evaluate the subscription successfully if the version and public key token of the assembly holding the messages you are publishing are identical on both publisher and subscriber.

The reason for this is that the subscription messages sent by the subscriber to the publisher on start up contain this information.

Check the subscription messages stored in the publishers subscription store and make sure the version/PKT match with the subscribers.

Comment: The versions match. I am taking the build output, copy it to the test machine and it stops working :(

Comment: Are you using transactional queues? If not then you could be dropping messages.

Comment: Are you storing your subscriptions durably? Msmq or db? Are you starting the host in the lite profile?

Comment: Sorry for not answering you, Andreas. I got no notification about your comment. We just tried to set `IsTransactional(false)` during bus setup. I'll try to enable transactional behavior again. We temporarily "solved" the problem by adding `Bus.Reply()` in addition to `Bus.Publish()` on this machine. The Reply gets delivered correctly.